# C# - foreach loop - Good Practice

Tags: c#, .net, performance, loops, foreach

Is this good or bad:

```
foreach (Match match in serverNameRegex.Matches(loginPage))
{
 ....
}
```

or should I use it like that for better speed:

```
MatchCollection matches = serverNameRegex.Matches(loginPage);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
  ...            
}
```

Comment: Well the question should be which is more readable

Comment: You are asking, is `serverNameRegex.Matches(loginPage)` re-evaluated on each iteration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as the `MatchCollection` cannot be null, I'd say it's your pick.

But if it turns out null and you don't check it beforehand, you will run into a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in speed whatsoever. It's a matter of style only.

In both cases, an `IEnumerator` is going to be created through the `GetEnumerator()` method. This happens only once. In every subsequent loop entry, only the method `MoveNext()` is going to be called.

Comment: actually in C# that's not necessarily true!

Comment: @MitchWheat, could you give a hint or link so I can read somewhere about it (speed in this case)?

Answer (score 3):

The second may be prefered since:

- You can easily sent a break point after it to track it (debug)
- If you need to make a change, you aren't also changing the loop (which should not be affected).
- Easier to read
- Nessesary if you want to add validations before the loop

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the latter, though there is no difference between them. Because the 2nd one seems to be clearer, and you can easily add more in the future.

```
MatchCollection matches = serverNameRegex.Matches(loginPage);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{

}
//do something to matches in the future
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no diffrence in that but i say **second one is more understandable, cleaner and easy to read that the first one.**

To check in details make use of deaasembler or reflator.

and for the second one is usefull if you want to user `matches` collection after foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

Depends if you will need `matches` in more places in your code. I think that it might be cleaner to use

```
foreach (Match match in serverNameRegex.Matches(loginPage))
{
}
```

because it will clean up the variable after the loop is done

Answer (score -2):

There is a speed difference between the two and the first one:

```
 foreach (Match match in serverNameRegex.Matches(loginPage))
 {
      ....
 }
```

is more faster.

Reason is, in the first one, serverNameRegex.Matches(loginPage) is evaluated once and the for loop already knows about each match value, whereas in:

```
 MatchCollection matches = serverNameRegex.Matches(loginPage);
 foreach (Match match in matches)
 {
    ...            
 }
```

the loop has to evaluate the matches collection in every iteration.